# Common Word including animals and humans?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm creating a youtube channel where i will upload interesting videos of animals and humans. But don't know the name. Anyone please let me know common word including animals and humans?

Comment: Hey, humans *are* animals, after all.

Comment: "Living" might do the trick.

Comment: 'Animals' itself is polysemous. Are bryozoa, for instance, to be included, or just mammals, or some arbitrary set?

Comment: @Laurel That post is no help either.

Comment: @Kris It may be no help, but it is still a duplicate. Possible answers should go there.

Comment: *Sentient* beings?

Comment: @DJohnson  I've never been convinced of the "sentience of the human" theory.

Comment: @Laurel "humans, animals, and possibly more categories to be determined later (e.g. spirits, monsters, undead?)." is not it.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/618962/2085).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could say something technically correct, but the context requires that both **humans and animals** be mentioned to be unambiguous and easier to understand. That's the best expression there.

The phrase is in extensive use both in formal and informal writing and is almost a technical term by itself.

If a phrase is acceptable rather than a single-word, then you already have it.

Answer (score -1):

Animals is rather broad term. Humans are a part of the "Animal Kingdom" and both animals and humans fall under the class "mammals".

Perhaps, your youtube channel could be called:

> The Mammalian Channel

It has a certain ring to it. But, this question is rather opinion-based, so whatever youtube channel name suits *you* is best. Perhaps try to be specific, is your youtube channel going to only look at specific animals and humans? "Humans" also has certain implications to coin videos of *people*, it almost sounds as if you're conducting experiments on them! Context is key.

Scientifically, humans are animals:

> Humans are members of a large group of animals known as mammals (Class Mammalia).

Source: https://australianmuseum.net.au/learn/science/human-evolution/humans-are-mammals/

Comment: Not all animals are mammals...